# Unity3d cannot found 64-bit plugin

Tags: macos, plugins, unity-game-engine

I wrote simple test osx plugin for Unity3d (contains one simple method - Test).

If I build plugin using universal or 64-bit architecture, then Unity3d did not find plugin (Unity3d write DllNotFoundException).

But if I build plugin using 32-bit architecture then all well. 
What is wrong?

Comment: Unity is only a 32 bit application (Unity 5 will have a 64 bit version as well). Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: There is a difference between 64bit dll's en 32bit dll's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer) There is because in player settings was set x86 architecture.